# mqtt publisher not working in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mqtt

i'm trying to make an android / ios app that publishes mqtt messages to a local server i'm using MQTTNET.
The Android version is working fine but when i try to run it on the ios one it just dosen't work

```
    public async Task connect(string channel,string message)
    {

        try
        {

            var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();

            IMqttClient client = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient();
            var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder().WithClientId(Guid.NewGuid()
                .ToString()).WithTcpServer("192.168.1.68").WithCleanSession().Build();


            client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("connected to the server");
                client.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(channel).Build());


            });


            client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("disconnected to the server");
            }); 



            await client.ConnectAsync(options);


            await PublishMessageAsync(client, message, channel);

            await client.DisconnectAsync();

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var o = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }

     static async Task PublishMessageAsync(IMqttClient client,string payload,string topic)
    {
        string messagePayload = payload;
        var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic(topic)
            .WithPayload(messagePayload)
            .WithAtLeastOnceQoS().Build();


        if (client.IsConnected)
        {
            await client.PublishAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

No error is shown, the debugger stops at client.connectAsync().

Comment: have you verified connectivity between your device and the server?

Comment: yes, i pinged the device from the server, and it recives fine @Jason

Comment: have you checked the other way?  That's where you are having problems

Comment: Yes, checked it and it works, i even published a message, but the code still not working.

Comment: I also checked, and it dosen't ask for network perms, even if i added them on entitelments.plist

Comment: And it also works on the simulator